# Getting most listened to tracks by country using Deezer api

Tags: deezer

I am trying to get the top 5 listened to (trending) tracks in deezer via the api. I do not see anything on the api exploration tool;
http://developers.deezer.com/api/explorer

Is it actually possible to retrieve trending tracks by country?

Answer (score 6):

You have to call `/chart` in the API to retrieve the top songs.

- http://api.deezer.com/chart/ <-- everything
- http://api.deezer.com/chart/0/tracks <-- only tracks
- http://api.deezer.com/chart/0/albums <-- only albums

I think you can't choose a specific country.

Answer (score 0):

You have to search for the top wordwide playlist and then access to that playlist and get the top five songs

[https://api.deezer.com/search/playlist/name?q='Top](https://api.deezer.com/search/playlist/name?q=%27Top) WorldWide'
[image]
As you see in the picture you have to ge

And then in the result you will have the id and the link to the playlist in the playlist object with the title 'Top WorldWide'

As well you can see the link to the top traks that you can use to get the top tracks as you see in the next picture

[image]